# How to calculate the cumulative mean of a block of the data frame up to each row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simplified dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
volume ask1 ask2 bid1 bid2
0      38   NA   38   37.9
100    38.1 38.2 37.8 38.2
0      38.4 38.5 38.2 38.3
0      38.4 38.5 38.2 NA
200    38.3 38.1 38   38.4
250    38.4 38.2 NA   38.6
```

I want to have another column, which contains the mean of `df[1:i, 2:5]` on the `i`th row.

I can do this with a for loop:

```
df[, "midpoint"] <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df$midpoint[i] <- mean(as.matrix(df[c(1:i), c(2:5)]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

But as my dataframe is actually large, the for loop takes a long time.

I have tried `sapply` but failed:

```
df[, "midpoint"] <- sapply(df, function(i) mean(as.matrix(df[c(1:i), c(2:5)]), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sapply` you can do :

```
mat <- as.matrix(df[, 2:5])
df$midpoint <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), function(i) mean(mat[1:i, ], na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

You can also take mean of means which would be faster but introduce a small error.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(res = rowMeans(select(., 2:5), na.rm = TRUE), 
         res = cummean(res))

#  volume ask1 ask2 bid1 bid2 midpoint      res
#1      0 38.0   NA 38.0 37.9 37.96667 37.96667
#2    100 38.1 38.2 37.8 38.2 38.02857 38.02083
#3      0 38.4 38.5 38.2 38.3 38.14545 38.13056
#4      0 38.4 38.5 38.2   NA 38.19286 38.18958
#5    200 38.3 38.1 38.0 38.4 38.19444 38.19167
#6    250 38.4 38.2   NA 38.6 38.22381 38.22639
```

Here `midpoint` is the actual answer from the for loop or `sapply` code and `res` is the answer from the above calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your `sapply` command, but you need to iterate over the number of rows.

Try

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) mean(as.matrix(df)[x, 2:5], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: somehow it gives me this warning: `In mean.default(as.matrix(df)[x, 2:5], na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`
I'm trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: This would indicate that some column vector in your data is not numeric.

Comment: Yes. Some of them are `NA`s. But I think `na.rm = TRUE` should do the job..

Comment: No, the `NA`s are not the problem. Some of them might be `character` or `factor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rowSums(cumsum(df[2:5]), na.rm=T) / cumsum(rowSums(!is.na(df[2:5])))
```